# what is the preferred way to have text instead of bullets with css (hanging indent)

Tags: css

What is the preferred methon to create something like

```
Apples   Apples can be
         green or red or
         more text more text

Bananas  Most of the time
         bananas are yellow
         (or green, if they're
         not ripe)

Item X   Each item should be aligned
         with the previous item, and
         each text (such as this 
         sentence) should be alligned
         with the previous text.
```

I have tried

```
.desc {
  margin-left: 140px;
  text-indent: -100px;
}

.item {
  width:100px;
}

...

<div class='desc'>
  <span class='item'>Apples</span> Apples can be green ....
</div>
```

But it didn't really give the result I expected (at least in Firefox).

Can someone help me here?

Thanks

René

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on data you want to use, but semantically speaking it seems like term and it's description, so `dl` hops in mind ^^

```
dt { display: block; float: left; width: 140px; }

<dl>
  <dt>Apples</dt>
  <dd>Description to it more lines of text to show it.</dd>
  <dt>Bananas</dt>
  <dd>Description to it more lines of text to show it.</dd>
  <dt>Lemon</dt>
  <dd>Description to it more lines of text to show it.</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 5):

Semantically, this looks like a case for the little-known `<dd>` and `<dt>` elements.

[**The W3C reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) has a nice example:

```
<DL>
  <DT>Dweeb
  <DD>young excitable person who may mature
    into a <EM>Nerd</EM> or <EM>Geek</EM>

  <DT>Hacker
  <DD>a clever programmer

  <DT>Nerd
  <DD>technically bright but socially inept person

</DL>
```

However, its default styling is not exactly what you want. Check out this article: 
[**Definition lists – misused or misunderstood?**](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/) 
it has a number of styling examples:

- Definition list with background images
- Definition list as boxes
- Styling a definition list to look like a table

Answer (score 0):

A real table wouldn't seem to be out of line here since you seem to have tabular data. In that case you would just use the normal table syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of a table myself, but since I might decide to have the "list" in a different visual format in some time to come, I hoped there would be a non-table solution.

Comment: If you might have to change it, then the definition list that others are recommending would definitely work. I just wanted to point out that there's nothing wrong with tables if you're using them the right way (i.e. not just for layout).

Comment: It does *not* look like tabular data to me.

Comment: Sure it is. Just imagine it with column headings like Term and Definition. If you had to have another column (say, for instance, References) you'd be stuck using a table instead of being able to use definition list.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's actually exactly a table display and nothing else. It's not a formatted list, it's not floated divs, it's not indented paragraphs. It's a table. I also think a table here is a superior solution to definition lists.

Answer (score 0):

Using a two-column `<table>` would be a good solution here, assuming it isn't a very very long table as this loads differently from a bunch of divs or other elements.

Using a table will also leave you with the flexibility of formatting individual elements inside cells as you want, such as a bulleted list inside a `<td>`.